# Add MVC 5 UserManager<ApplicationUser> to register with Unity Framework?

Tags: unity-container, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Hi i am using MVC 5 + EF6 and want to register  MVC 5 Application User and other specific types using Unity 3 but i am getting errors.

**My Context Class:**

```
public class ProjectContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public ProjectContext()
        : base("ProjectContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfile { get; set; }


    public virtual void Commit()
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


    }
}
```

**Controller Class:**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager;
    private IUserService userService;
    private IUserProfileService userProfileService;



    public AccountController(IUserService userService, IUserProfileService userProfileService, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.userProfileService = userProfileService;
        this.UserManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

*I have used the following registration in combinations but i am getting errors*

--> ProjectArchitecture.Web.Controllers.AccountController does not have a constructor that takes the parameters (). When all 1-4 are commented above

-->  The type DbConnection does not have an accessible constructor.

**Unity Registration Code:**

```
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
        container.RegisterType<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>, RoleStore<IdentityRole>>();
        container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
        container.RegisterInstance(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new     UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ProjectEntities())));
```

Comment: Did you register your Unity `IDependencyResolver` onto MVC? Did you use the [integration package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/)?

Comment: @Steven Yes i did used integration package and did all what i can but no success

Comment: @Steven what you exactly mean when you say "Did you register your Unity IDependencyResolver onto MVC" i think integration package do that for us. please help here

Comment: Somewhere in your code there must be a call to `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));`. Make sure that line gets executed.

Comment: @Steven After lots of playing around with the Unity config file i finally got it resolved by adding the following to the Unity config file, please confirm if this is the perfect answer, i am very early in creating the architecture of my project and dont want it to break after i am way ahead with it


container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>,
            UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new InjectionConstructor(new context()));